# Open pdf file whose file name contains a string

Tags: c#, pdf

Well, I want to open pdf file whose name contains certain string.

this is a code that I used to see is there a file whose name contains a string:

```
if (Directory.EnumerateFiles(startInfo.Arguments).Any(PDFfile=>PDFfile.Contains(myString)))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Jackpot");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("There is no file!");
}
```

I get "Jackpot" msg, now how to open that file?! I know that I should use:

```
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

But this is when you have exactly specified path to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it a few ways, one way could be this:

```
var filesInDirectory = Directory.EnumerateFiles(startInfo.Arguments);
var pdfFile = filesInDirectory.FirstOrDefault(PDFfile=>PDFfile.Contains(myString));
var pdfFileExists = pdfFile != null;

if (pdfFileExists)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Jackpot");
    Process.Start(pdfFile);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("There is no file!");
}
```

Note that the `FirstOrDefault` would cause it to grab the first result it comes to, unsure if this is the result you are looking for.

Comment: Modified it a little bit and it worked like a charm!!! thanks Arran, you've been of great help!